# iOS json Parser Breaks on Large Files?

Tags: json, ios5

I'm using the iOS NSJSONSerialization and it used to work fine but I doubled the amount of data and now it fails to parse. When I look at NSLog it tries about 4-5 times and gives me nulls. The data looks fine. Has anybody had this problem? Do you know how to go about fixing it?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you introduced an error in the JSON when doubling the data depending on how you did it. Maybe a comma missing or a closing bracket somewhere? Happened to me before.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, Roko. I haven't paid attention to how the system works – now I know and I'll reward the people who generously help and I will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

how large a file are you using? I typically parse through 1-5MB json files. Though I would also recommend SBJson. Any code snippets or other examples to give us a better idea of what you are doing would be helpful.

Comment: The code is: NSError *error;
 self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
 
 NSLog(@"json = %@", self.json);

Answer (score 0):

How big is the data? I am parsing around 700Kb every time my app starts and it does it fine.